# Sending emails are not received outside the company using System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, exchange-server, system.net.mail

I am using the following code in order to send emails. The emails are received successfully to the recipients at works but they are not received outside. I tried to send an email to my gmail account and same issue, I cannot received it.
At work, we are using Exchange 2010. I checked junk in gmail and no emails were found.

My Code:

```
    public bool SendEmail()
    {
        try
        {
            var mailMessage = CreateMailMessage();

            var client = new SmtpClient()
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Resources.Username, Resources.Password, Resources.Domain),
                Port = 25,                    
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Host = ConfigurationProperties.ExchangeIPAddress
            };

            client.Send(mailMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogFile.Write(string.Format("EmailManager::SendEmail failed at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));
            LogFile.Write(string.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message));
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private MailMessage CreateMailMessage()
    {
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage();

        mailMessage.Subject = ConfigurationProperties.EmailSubject;
        mailMessage.Body = ConfigurationProperties.EmailBody;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        mailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

        LogFile.Write(string.Format("Subject= {0}", mailMessage.Subject));
        LogFile.Write(string.Format("Body= {0}", mailMessage.Body));

        AddRecipients(mailMessage);

        return mailMessage;
    }
```

Is there any property I am missing in order to let outside emails recipients for receiving the emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no property that you can set to allow the mails to go outside of your network. This sounds like a configuration on your Exchange server and nothing to do with System.Net.Mail.

You'll need to talk with your system administrator.

Comment: I was just about to answer to my own question, You are correct, this was a configuration in the Exchange itself. Thank you